# How to show multiple date selection on bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker inline calendar. I need to show a selection when the user clicks on the day boxes on this calendar. Right now when the user clicks on the day it shows a selection but when clicking on another day it removes the selection from the previous one. I need to show the selection on all days that the user clicked. how do achieve this? Please check image for a better understanding.
[image]

I have tried to add an active class on click on the day. But it's not working.

```
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker-days table tbody tr td', function () {
   $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

bootstrap file name is for datepicker -- tempusdominus-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 0):

The documentation contains, the following class: input-daterange

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#daterange

[image]